# Does SOAP always need WSDL?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

Does SOAP always need WSDL or can it work without WSDL? I've been doing some reading on the internet and it's making me confused.

From what I can see, SOAP request can contain the message in the XML: http://www.w3schools.com/soap/soap_example.asp. Then why do I need WSDL? Or does it depend on how the SOAP service is set up in the server end?

Answer (score 6):

WSDL is a description of the service (Web Service Description Language).  It is mainly used to a) describe the service in a non-ambiguous way, and b) allow tools to generate client and/or server code, which make building, and interacting with, the service easier.

You can certainly implement, or interact with, a SOAP service "by hand" but you wouldn't want to.